# Hacking Vehicles in Watch Dogs

Tags: watch-dogs

I have been playing Watch Dogs since it came out and i recently did the mission called "Not A Job for Tyrone" and my friend did this mission to. But what i wanted to ask about is how i hack a car. What i mean by that is, everytime i steal a car, i need to break the glass to get into the car. But my friend does only need to press Triangle (on PS4) and he just opens the car like if he has the keys to unlock it. But i do not have it. We've done the same missions and everything but still, nothing. Is it maybe because i haven't unlocked any ctOS towers? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In Watch_Dogs you can use skill points gotten from missions and whatnot to get hacking skills, combat skills, etc. The first skill in the Driving tree is the ability to unlock all cars and disable their alarms when you enter.

Comment: @xPubHD the answer might be worth to be [accepted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a skill required to unlock cars using your phone. To unlock the skill press up on your D-pad and select skills menu item. Go to the driving tree, the first skill unlocks vehicles using you phone.